# php - how to add two associative arrays to the same array key

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add two associative arrays to the same array key or take out only from the array the keys I need like the example below, the keys I need in the fields array `$field = [a,b];`.

Lets say I have the blow array:

```
array1 = Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
            [c] => c
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
            [c] => c
        )

)

$field = [a,b];
$x = [];

foreach ($array1 as $key) {
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $x[$key['id']] = array($field => $key[$field]);
      }
}
print_r($x);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [b] => b
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [b] => b
        )

)
```

I need:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
        )

)
```

Comment: Array merge? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are assigning a new array everytime, what you need to do is the below code where in you are only assigning the new index and not the array.

```
<?php $array1 = array(
'key1' => array
    (
        'a' => "a",
        'b' => "b",
        'c' => "c"
    ),
'key2' => array
    (
        'a' => "a",
        'b' => "b",
        'c' => "c"
    )

);

$fields = array('a','b');
$x = [];

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if(array_key_exists($field,$array1[$key]))
            $x[$key][$field] = $value[$field];
    }
}
print_r($x);
```

Comment: error `Undefined index: key1 in ... array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in`

Comment: thanks, I cant upvote for your answer, need more then 15 rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, by reconstruct another multidimensional with only keys that are in `$field` array.

Here is the code :

```
$field = array('a','b');
$x     = array();

foreach ($array1 as $k => $key) {
    foreach ($fields as $k2 => $field) {
        if(in_array($k2, $field))
            $x[$k][$k2] = $field;
    }
}

print_r($x);
```

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard. I changed... ;-)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The qestion is not there, if its code is not optimized, it is not our role. Is it ? I help him rebuild his multidimensional array which is his question. But it is clear that we can always do better and to declare an array for a,b directly is better.  But, in the same time, @Berlain changed syntax. so now he has an array. So I modify my answer.

Comment: error `PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in `

Comment: So, your $field is not an array. please make an array like I did instead of [a,b]. use array('a', 'b');

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    'key1'=>array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c'),
    'key2'=>array('a'=>'a','b'=>'b','c'=>'c'),
    'key3'=>array('c'=>'c')
);

$include = array('a','b');

foreach($arr as &$res)
{
    $res = array_filter($res, function($key) use ($include) {
            return in_array($key, $include);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
unset($res);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Test Results

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [key1] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
        )

    [key2] => Array
        (
            [a] => a
            [b] => b
        )

    [key3] => Array
        (
        )

)
```